# ¿Como hago funcionar android volley con datos móviles?

Tags: android, android-volley

Tengo una aplicación android que manda un par de string a mi servidor local y guardarlos en una BD, para esto uso **volley** la cual funciona perfecto cuando realizo el envió desde emulador.

El problema viene cuando realizo el envió desde un móvil físico.

1 -Si realizo el envió con red wifi lo hace sin problemas.

2 -Si apago la red wifi y hago el envió con datos móviles me manda mensaje de **TimeoutError**, ya le di hasta minuto y medio de espera y no recibo respuesta del servidor.(termino recibiendo el mismo error)

El Internet tengo ya que lo compruebo con  `NetworkInfo mMobile = connManager2.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE` y ademas obtengo mi ubicación que es uno de los datos que quiero enviar y la trae sin problemas con red móvil o con wifi".

En resumen el problema de enviar con volley ocurre unicamente con datos moviles, no con wifi, no con emulador. Mi pregunta es si necesito alguna conf en especial que se me ha pasado, algun consejo?

Comment: Riu, bienvenid@ a SOes. Te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y visitar el articulo [ask]. Se muy poco de Android y "volley" pero tus parrafos me suenan a problemas de red.

Comment: Estas seguro que tienes datos móviles ?

Comment: Así es, las pruebas las hice en 3 celulares diferentes, todos reciben mensajes whatsap, facebook y me traen mi ubicación actual. 
El único problema viene cuando envió los datos como mencione.

Comment: No necesitas ninguna configuración especial. Básicamente necesitas saldo en tu cuenta de datos móviles. Y si la conexión es demasiado lenta, aumentar el tiempo de espera. Quizá has liado *algo raro* en tu código tratando de identificar si la conexión es móvil o no. Eso no tiene ninguna utilidad. Yo uso Volley con o sin datos móviles, todo igual, sin tener que distinguir nada. Por cierto, verifica que tienes la `Volley` de Android, porque hay una Volley que es obsoleta.

Comment: Como ya mencione ya he cambiado el tiempo de espera a 2 minutos que fue mi ultimo intento, la aplicación espera pero no recibe respuesta lo que se traduce en el error mencionado. En cuanto a la verificación de red únicamente lo incluí para confirmar la conexión.

Comment: Es que en Volley no tienes que confirmar conexión. Volley tiene un método `onErrorResponse` desde el cual puedes manejar todos los errores, incluida la falta de conexión. A través del código de error puedes saber exactamente lo que está pasado al hacer la petición.

Comment: Así es ya he cambiado todo eso por  `error instanceof NoConnectionError` y `error instanceof NetworkError` los cuales comente ya que el único error que manda es el mencionado `TimeoutError` y solo con datos móviles, con emulador y con wifi trabaja perfecto.

Comment: @Riu Te sugiero agregues más detalles a la hora de preguntar, Agrega tu código y permisos que tienes definidos. puedes estar solo revisando si la conectividad de red es posible pero no si  es posible establecer conexión.