# Cree una consulta a un servidor web utilizando volley marca error de espero cuando activo los datos del movil, con conexiòn wifi si funciona

Tags: volley

He estado buscando la saluciòn al problema de mi aplicacion movil. siempre compile la aplicacion utilizando el wifi, pero en el momento de utilizarla con los datos del telefono, marca erro de conexion. buscando soluciones me sugirieron que cambiar la versiòn del volley, ya la instale a la 1.1.1. no me funcionò. tambien me dijeron agregara el siguiente codigo al final de la consulta y nada.

```
int socketTimeout = 5000; // 30 seconds. You can change it RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,3, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
```

he aumentado el 5000 hasta 100000 y el problema persiste.
les comparto el codigo que tengo

```
private void buscarUsuario(String URL) { JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener() { @Override public void onResponse(JSONArray response) { JSONObject jsonObject = null; for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) { try { jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i); tvnombreUs.setText(jsonObject.getString("nombres")); variables_globales.tp_usuario= (jsonObject.getString("tipo")); variables_globales.contrasena_us= (jsonObject.getString("clave")); variables_globales.porcentaje_utd= Integer.parseInt (jsonObject.getString("porcentaje")); indica_consulta = 2; progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); tvacceso.setEnabled(true); tvregistro.setEnabled(true); btningresar.setEnabled(true);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if(indica_consulta == 0){
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tvregistro.setEnabled(true);
                tvnombreUs.setText("Registrese...");
            }
        }
    }
    );


    int socketTimeout = 5000; // 30 seconds. You can change it
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,3,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

    jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);


}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo no programar todo en una sola línea. Sobre todo a la hora de compartir el código con los demás, hace que sea mucho más difícil comprender qué hace.

Comment: como puedo editar la pregunta para corregir soy nuevo en esto

Comment: En la parte de abajo, justo debajo de las etiquetas, te sale una barra con diferentes opciones, entre ellas editar

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar la pregunta. También revisa el Log cat y agrega a la pregunta la traza completa del error.

Comment: Gracias. Ya esta mejor organizada la información. agradezco sus ayudas. He buscado soluciones y no he encontre una que sirva. Todo lo he aprendido sobre android studio ha sido a traves de este medio, de antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Hola Benito me puede colaborar, agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Revisa el Log cat de Android Studio, ahí te mostrará el mensaje de error completo. Agrégalo a la pregunta para ver cuál es el motivo del error.

Comment: Les agradezco que me ayuden. no hay mucha información en internet sobre este problema que tengo con mi proyecto.

Comment: en esta pagina alguien ya hizo una  pregunta muy similiar a la que yo estoy planteando, pero no hubo respuesta oportuna. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142655/como-hago-funcionar-android-volley-con-datos-m%C3%B3viles